# How do I speed up fractal generation with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a little script I wrote for making fractals using newton's method.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.poly1d([1,0,0,-1]) # x^3 - 1
fp = np.polyder(f)

def newton(i, guess):
    if abs(f(guess)) > .00001:
        return newton(i+1, guess - f(guess)/fp(guess))
    else:
        return i

pic = []
for y in np.linspace(-10,10, 1000):
    pic.append( [newton(0,x+y*1j) for x in np.linspace(-10,10,1000)] )

plt.imshow(pic)
plt.show()
```

I am using numpy arrays, but nonetheless loop through each element of 1000-by-1000 linspaces to apply the `newton()` function, which acts on a single guess and not a whole array.

My question is this: **How can I alter my approach to better exploit the advantages of numpy arrays?**

P.S.: If you want to try the code without waiting too long, better to use 100-by-100.

Extra background:
See Newton's Method for finding zeroes of a polynomial.
The basic idea for the fractal is to test guesses in the complex plane and count the number of iterations to converge to a zero.  That's what the recursion is about in `newton()`, which ultimately returns the number of steps.  A guess in the complex plane represents a pixel in the picture, colored by the number of steps to convergence.  From a simple algorithm, you get these beautiful fractals.

Comment: thanks for asking this. this is helping me understand how to make them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked from Lauritz V. Thaulow's code and was able to get a pretty significant speed-up with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count

def newton_fractal(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xres, yres):
    yarr, xarr = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xres), \
                             np.linspace(ymin, ymax, yres) * 1j)
    arr = yarr + xarr
    ydim, xdim = arr.shape
    arr = arr.flatten()
    f = np.poly1d([1,0,0,-1]) # x^3 - 1
    fp = np.polyder(f)
    counts = np.zeros(shape=arr.shape)
    unconverged = np.ones(shape=arr.shape, dtype=bool)
    indices = np.arange(len(arr))
    for i in count():
        f_g = f(arr[unconverged])
        new_unconverged = np.abs(f_g) > 0.00001
        counts[indices[unconverged][~new_unconverged]] = i
        if not np.any(new_unconverged):
            return counts.reshape((ydim, xdim))
        unconverged[unconverged] = new_unconverged
        arr[unconverged] -= f_g[new_unconverged] / fp(arr[unconverged])

N = 1000
pic = newton_fractal(-10, 10, -10, 10, N, N)

plt.imshow(pic)
plt.show()
```

For N=1000, I get a time of 11.1 seconds using Lauritz's code and a time of 1.7 seconds using this code.

There are two main speed-ups here. First, I used meshgrid to speed-up the creation of the numpy array of input values. This is actually a pretty significant part of the speed-up when N=1000.

The second speed-up comes from only doing calculations on the unconverged portions. Lauritz was using masked arrays for this before realizing that they were slowing things down. I haven't looked at them in quite some time, but I do remember masked arrays being a source of slowness in the past. I believe it is because they are largely implemented in pure Python over a numpy array rather than being written almost completely in C like numpy arrays.

Comment: @Tobal I'm afraid that I don't understand your meaning. I just ran the code without incident. I also don't understand what you mean by 'z^4-1 infinite loop'.

Answer (score 4):

I vectorized the newton function and got approx. 85 times faster with 200x200 points, 144 times faster with 500x500 points, and 148 times faster with 1000x1000 points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.poly1d([1,0,0,-1]) # x^3 - 1
fp = np.polyder(f)
def newton(i, guess):            
    a = np.empty(guess.shape,dtype=int)
    a[:] = i
    j = np.abs(f(guess))>.00001
    if np.any(j):         
        a[j] = newton(i+1, guess[j] - np.divide(f(guess[j]),fp(guess[j])))        
    return a

npts = 1000
x = np.linspace(-10,10,npts)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,npts)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pic = np.reshape(newton(0,np.ravel(xx+yy*1j)),[npts,npts])
plt.imshow(pic)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my stab at it. It is about 16 times faster.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count

def newton_fractal(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xres, yres):
    arr = np.array([[x + y * 1j for x in np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xres)] \
        for y in np.linspace(ymin, ymax, yres)], dtype="complex")
    f = np.poly1d([1,0,0,-1]) # x^3 - 1
    fp = np.polyder(f)
    counts = np.zeros(shape=arr.shape)
    for i in count():
        f_g = f(arr)
        converged = np.abs(f_g) <= 0.00001
        counts[np.where(np.logical_and(converged, counts == 0))] = i
        if np.all(converged):
            return counts
        arr -= f_g / fp(arr)

pic = newton_fractal(-10, 10, -10, 10, 100, 100)

plt.imshow(pic)
plt.show()
```

I'm not a numpy expert, I'm sure those that are can optimalize it some more, but already it's a huge improvement in terms of speed.

**EDIT:** It turned out the masked arrays didn't help at all, removing them resulted in a 15% speed *increase*, so I've removed the masked arrays from the above solution. Can anyone explain why the masked arrays didn't help?

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm still reading and understanding your method.  Why the masked array?

Comment: @mrKelley It's to avoid running any more computations on the elements that have converged. It should work the same but slower if you just use a regular array.

Comment: Ahh... that makes sense, very nice.

Comment: @mrKelly It made sense in *theory*. In practice... not so much. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved the infinite loop in code of Justin Peel adding a max iterations condition in the code, now the code plots polynomials like z^4-1 and it doesn't enter in an infinite loop. If someone knows how to improve this bug please let us know. My solution, perhaps makes slower the execution of the code but it works.
This is the code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import numpy as np
    import itertools
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    __author__ = 'Tobal'
    __version__ = 1.0


    def newton_fractal(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xres, yres, tolerance, maxiters):
        yarr, xarr = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xres), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, yres) * 1j)
        arr = yarr + xarr
        ydim, xdim = arr.shape
        arr = arr.flatten()
        fp = np.polyder(f, m=1)
        counts = np.zeros(shape=arr.shape)
        unconverged = np.ones(shape=arr.shape, dtype=bool)
        indices = np.arange(len(arr))
        iters = 0
        for i in itertools.count():
            f_g = f(arr[unconverged])
            new_unconverged = np.abs(f_g) > tolerance
            counts[indices[unconverged][~new_unconverged]] = i
            if not np.any(new_unconverged) or iters >= maxiters:
                return counts.reshape((ydim, xdim))
            iters += 1
            unconverged[unconverged] = new_unconverged
            arr[unconverged] -= f_g[new_unconverged] / fp(arr[unconverged])


    pic = newton_fractal(np.poly1d([1., 0., 0., 0., -1.]), -10, 10, -10, 10, 1000, 1000, 0.00001, 1000)
    plt.imshow(pic, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gnuplot'))
    plt.title(r'$Newton^{\prime} s\;\;Fractal\;\;Of\;\;P\,(z) =z^4-1$', fontsize=18, y=1.03)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

I'm using Pycharm 5 with Anaconda Python 3 and this IDE reports a warning in the code  **not np.any(new_unconverged)**

> Expected 'type Union[ndarray, iterable]', got 'bool' instead

This warning appears in the original Justin Peel code, too; and I don't konw how to solve it. I'm very interested with this problem.
[image: Newton's Fractal]