# Can I convert complex valued meshgrid data into real valued data without losing information?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on an implementation of Newton's fractal, and this is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.poly1d([1,0,0,0,1,0,-1]) # x^3 - 1
fp = np.polyder(f)
rts = f.r
def newton(z0, f, fp, MAX_IT=1000):
    TOL = 1e-8
    z = z0
    for i in range(MAX_IT):
        dz = np.divide(f(z),fp(z))
        adz = np.absolute(dz)
        if np.any(adz < TOL) :
            return z
        z -= dz
    return False

npts = 1000
x = np.linspace(-1,1,npts)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,npts)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pic = newton(np.ravel(xx+yy*1j),f,fp)
```

I took inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17396847) answer and modified the implementation of Newton's Method. My problem is that `pic` has complex entries, and `plt.imshow` doesn't accept that type of data.

I've tried using `2*cos(np.angle(zz))` on `pic` and this is what I got:[image]

Which sort of works, but not really. **This** is what I want:[image]

So, my question is: can I convert my data into a form that `plt.imshow` will accept *without* losing information, and if not, what alternative methods can I use to get the same result? I would prefer that the vectorization of the method is preserved, as it is faster and more efficient (in my opinion).

Comment: besides `angle` , there's `real` and `imag`.  See the neighboring doc pages.

Comment: @hpaulj I know about `real` and `imag`. My question is in reference to encoding information from both real and imaginary parts of the complex number into one _real_ number, and passing that real number to `plt.imshow`. I don't want to use `abs` or similar functions because i need the information from both parts of the complex number in order to get something similar to the second image.

Comment: I worked with complex math years ago before imaging was common, so don't know what your colors show.  Complex data can have all sorts of cuts, branches,  and planes as the terms change signs or go to inf.

Comment: @hpaulj The colors represent which root the complex number represented by the pixel converged to.

Comment: A complex number is really just two real values.  Complex theory has lots of ideas on how to present that `a+ib`, `x,y`, magnitude and phase/angle, etc..  If magnitude is normalized, then phase is enough.

Comment: @hpaulj I've normalized my data, and passed the phases to `plt.imshow`. It worked! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, **there is no need to convert your data from the complex numebrs**, as you only need to assign each unique value a different color (with some tolerance).

Here are a few guidelines to help you attain the desired outcomes:

For each pixel, calculate the following values:

- The root to which Newton’s method converged
- How many iterations it took to reach the root

After that, you need to assign each root a different color and for each pixel use the corresponding color scaled by the number of iterations.

Your function currently appears to return the converged root for each pixel, however your implementation is not correct, since you return the entire array `z0` when any of the values converges. The magic of Newton's fractal is that each pixel converges at a different rate!

I highly recommend to check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397203/6300197) you linked as your inspiration and make sure you understand the algorithm. Their implementation calculates the number of iterations it takes to reach the root. You can modify their implementation to also return the converged root and create the visualization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you suggest I extend this program for functions where it is either computationally expensive to find their roots beforehand, or have an infinite number of roots? I want to color pixels because the complex number they converged are equal (with some tolerance), not necessarily because they match a number in a predefined root list.

Comment: You do not need to find the roots beforehand. You can assign the colors after the calculations -- one color for each distinct value in the final array (with tolerance). You don't need to worry about infinite number of roots, as all finite polynomial functions have finite number of roots.